# What is the solid angle $d\Omega$ in radiative transfer?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, mathematical-physics, radiation, radiative-transfer

The Wikipedia article for [radiative transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer) gives the following definition:

> In terms of the spectral radiance, $I_{\nu }$, the energy flowing across an area element of area $da$, located at $\mathbf{r}$ in time $dt$, in the solid angle $d\Omega$ about the direction ${\hat {\mathbf {n} }}$ in the frequency interval $\nu +d\nu$, is
> $$dE_{\nu }=I_{\nu }(\mathbf {r} ,{\hat {\mathbf {n} }},t)\cos \theta \ d\nu \,da\,d\Omega \,dt,$$
> where $\theta$  is the angle that the unit direction vector ${\hat {\mathbf {n} }}$ makes with a normal to the area element.

It isn't clear to me what the solid angle $d\Omega$ is supposed to be. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transport_theory

Comment: Typing "solid angle" in google yields this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solid angle is a 3 dimensional angle.  See this [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/photom.html#:%7E:text=The%20power%20(flux)%20per%20unit,expressed%20in%20watts%20per%20steradian.) and this image with red box:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) is not special to your use-case,
but used much more widely.

The solid angle $\Omega$ is simply defined as the ratio of a surface area
element $A$ of a sphere and its squared radius $R^2$:
$$\Omega=\frac{A}{R^2}$$

[image: solid angle]
<sub>(image from this [math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032927/volume-inside-a-solid-solid-angle))</sub>

The same goes when you have a small infinitesimal solid angle $d\Omega$
and surface area element $dA$:
$$d\Omega=\frac{dA}{R^2}$$